# $\chi(G) \cdot \chi(\bar{G})\geq n$

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that  $\chi(G) \cdot \chi(\bar{G})\geq n$

$\chi(G)$: number of colors required for a graph $G$.

Here $\bar{G}$ is a graph that consists of all the edges that are not in $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer of your question is available [here](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=A_bound_for_the_product_of_the_chromatic_number_of_a_graph_and_its_complement)

Comment: Please summarize the proof here, so it won't get lost if the link breaks.

Comment: @vonbrand Hopefully I should make sure the link does not break.